# CSS issues in IE using margins and Tables

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a site ,The problem is when I view it in Chrome or Firefox it looks ok but when I view it in IE 8 or IE 9 the three columns on homepage doesnt come in order.The footer also disappears.i dont know whats the reason behind it.i have even debugged the code but could find the clue.I can write code for all browsers by detecting first the browser and then executing appropriate code for it,but that wouldn't be a nice way i believe.i want to know the reason behind this.Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Remove comment before the doctype.

Comment: @duri This could be the reason?

Comment: i just removed the header comment but then the search bar vanished from its place,I dont know what is the impace of comment on IE...

Comment: Please do not tag your question [html5][css3] if it's **not** about HTML5 or CSS3.

Comment: @BoltClock I thought may be these guys also suffered the same problem..

Comment: @ZainShah120 - The comment before the doctype will put IE into quirks mode. That's why it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

There's several 'anomalies' that come to mind:

1.- why would you use such an outdated doc declaration?:

```
<!--header-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
```

Please change the above to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
```

That includes removing `<!-- header --->` and the blank space from the first 2 lines.

2.- Why are you using `<font>`? near the footer. I know it's commented out but what's the deal with that?

3.- You might want to clean your code by adding indentation and `<!-- #element or .class ends here -->` tags after closing blocks to know what is what.

4.- On line 131 you have:

```
<div id="table_three" style="width:300px; height:100px;margin: -100px 0px 20px 680px;"">
```

Smart browsers like chrome and firefox 'fix' the mess but IE does not. That double quote near the end is surely causing havoc in IE's eyes.

5.- What program are you using to code this? You could benefit by using something that assists you in identifying these kinds of code breakers.

6.- Your wrappers and container divs don't have display:block; and overflow:hidden; which helps the browser render inner divs with floats and what not.

Apply the above and let me know so we can do some extra clean-up

EDIT: Also found:

7.- Rogue `<script>` tags in the middle of the document

8.- Ghost `<div></div>`'s in several places

9.- An odd login form inside `#header` that I removed for my test purposes

10.- Inline style `(css)` declarations: a no-no given the situation.

11.- misplaced `<!-- closing tags`

12.- redundant opening tag notes such as `<!--- header starts here`

13.- using the `<strong>` element with class `.bold` for it when strong already has bold by default...individually per each word of each link sentence... oh my

Comment: If i f i remove the header comment then the search bar also moves from its position

Comment: Now the footer has some problem...

Comment: Why did you remove the link to your page from the original post? I was going to do some tests with it to troubleshoot the error...

Comment: In any case, here's my 'cleaned up' version: http://sotkra.com/test.html It has missing images and I removed some post entries but its essentially the same thing

Comment: Footer is there for me in all versions of IE. It is only in ie7 that it breaks the page horizontally. In any case...please take a look at the markup code....I cleaned it up bigtime.

Comment: Hell, I even fixed the css for the searchbar which is what was breaking the page for ie7